# Is the phrase 'at your Beckon Call' marked with servitude or with politeness?

Tags: phrases

I recently entered into an argument with my Mom regarding it's apt use. Though traditionally, it implied servitude, but hasn't it's meaning changed over the years?
Basically, is using it to a Professor/Higher Authority convey servitude or politeness?

Comment: The phrase is "*at your beck and call*". And yes it's  servile/unctuous, *especially* to a higher authority  (that makes it *worse*; saying it to a buddy who's sick in bed, or a cute girl after a first date, is using it ironically, preciously; saying it to a *professor* is another thing altogether).

Comment: Neither servitude not mere politeness. It lies somewhere in between. See a dictionary/ search online for the idiom "beck and call."

Comment: That's what Tim and Josh have done, and their references describe "*beck and call*" as "entirely subservient" and "pretentious" respectively. But if you want to find more/better/different references, go ahead and add an answer of your own (that's why OP is asking *here*, and the question is on topic).

Comment: I believe I once read a science fiction novel (possibly one of Zahn's *Star Wars* novels) involving a device that would summon a starship to automatically fly to its owner.  The device was called a *beckon call*, presumably a nod to this [eggcorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn).

Comment: Should we be paging Mrs. Malaprop, or Lady Mondegreen?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I belive it is "*beck and call**":

> Beck and call
>
> To be at someone's beck and call is to be entirely subservient to them; to be responsive to their slightest request.

Call has it's normal meaning, however:

> 'Beck' is more interesting. The word, despite having been in use in English since the 1300s century, isn't one that is found outside of this phrase. It is merely a shortened form of 'beckon'

(NB "*isn't one that is found outside of this phrase*" isn't strictly true - it also means a small stream. I assume that that quote means it is only used meaning "beckon" when in this phrase).

"entirely subservient" - so the answer is servitude.

Quotes are from [phrases.org](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/beck-and-call.html)

Comment: How do you [make sense of the ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beck%2Cbeck+and+call%2Cbeckon%2Cbeck+and&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeck%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeck%20and%20call%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeckon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeck%20and%3B%2Cc0) that indicate beck much more widely used than beck and call, or for that matter, even the word beckon? (beck is defined as a mountain stream, or bow or curtsy).

Comment: Yeah a brook, or a shortening of beckon, but only in this phrase. It is used more than "beck and call" because it has more than 1 meaning - more opportunities for it to be used.

Comment: @SrJoven, edited, that should clarify.

Comment: _beck_ is also used without the _and call_ as far back as _beck and call_ is used, in the simpler phrase _at his beck_.

Comment: @Frank, but that has fallen out of usage now?

Comment: I've never heard _beck_ in either the sense of `to make a mute signal, or significant gesture, as by nodding, shaking the fore-finger,etc`-OED1 or _to have someone under your orders or absolute control_ which is roughly how OED2 describes it. The OED2 sense (which includes _beck and call_ is not in OED1) and the quotations between 1 & 2 are very different. Looks like _beck_ underwent a serious update from 1 to 2, losing a 14c quotation in the process. `a.1300 E.E.Psalter xxxiv. 19 Whilk Þat hates me wilfulli, And beckes with Þair eghen lesli`

Comment: Here's a blend of _beck/becks/becked_ pre 1500. http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED3966&egs=all&egdisplay=open Notice Psalter is dated as after 1400 there.

Comment: It's still not marked as obsolete in OED online and it has been updated slightly since OED2. So... has it fallen out of usage? Doesn't look like it, there are plenty 21st century books with _at his beck_ without the _and call_.

Comment: @Frank That is worthy of your own answer! I honestly got lost reading that!

Answer (score 5):

[Beckon call](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=beckon%20call), from Urban Dictionary:

> - A misinterpretation of the phrase "beck and call" such as "at ones beck and call" meaning to be at willful readiness to fulfill another's orders or commands. It is usually used by people who are attempting to sound more well read than are are in actuality.
>
>   - "Professor Stackhouse has us at his beckon call."

According to the [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/beck-and-call.html):

> - The misspelling began in the USA in the early 20th century.
>
>   - Just because 'beckon call' is based on a mishearing doesn't mean that it won't one day become accepted as proper English. Other phrases, like 'beg the question' for instance, are routinely used incorrectly by so many people that the incorrect usage has now become the standard. Let's hope 'beckon call' dies a natural death, not only because it is essentially just a spelling mistake but because its adoption would signal the last gasp of the enjoyable little word 'beck'.

As Dan Bron has nicely pointed out in his comment the expression is servile and used especially with higher authorities.

Answer (score 0):

Richard Gere uses the "beck and call" phrase as a demand to Julia Roberts when his character hires hers as a [call girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_girl) in the movie [Pretty Woman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Woman). So yes, it implies subservience.